# How to play sounds at varying speeds?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to play a sound (G5.wav) that lasts exactly one second at varying speeds without changing the pitch, what module can I use to achieve this?

I have already tried using `pydub` but I simply get too many errors when trying to import any sound. Any advice helps `:)`

Comment: What OS are you using? I suggest you add a tag for it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Winsound is a great module for playing sounds.

Example of how it works:

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound(sound.wav)
```

In your case you want:

```
winsound.PlaySound(G5.wav)
```

If it doesn’t work than add quotation marks or put the file path instead.

Here's the relevant `winsound` [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/winsound.html)

Comment: Thank you, is there any function that allows me to change the speed OR duration of the sound but keep the pitch the same?

Comment: Well I haven’t played around with it too much but I do believe you can do this with winsound, hence why I provided the documentation as it may be found in there. If a module can’t do it then you can always try it yourself with a sound editing program.

Comment: Where in the documentation does it say you can change the speed or duration?

Comment: @Peter: It doesn't, however it does state the it provides access to (only) "the **basic** sound-playing machinery provided by Windows platforms" (emphasis mine)—so you'll need to find another (probably third-party) module/library to do what you want. Another alternative might be to use the `ctypes` module to make direct call(s) to the Windows API that handles sound.